# Scroll to position WITHIN a div (not window) using pure JS

Tags: javascript, scroll, anchor

PURE JS ONLY PLEASE - NO JQUERY

I have a div with overflow scroll, the window (html/body) never overflows itself.

I have a list of anchor links and want to scroll to a position when they're clicked.

Basically just looking for anchor scrolling from within a div, not window.

window.scrollTo etc. don't work as the window never actually overflows.

Simple test case http://codepen.io/mildrenben/pen/RPyzqm

JADE

```
nav
  a(data-goto="#1") 1
  a(data-goto="#2") 2
  a(data-goto="#3") 3
  a(data-goto="#4") 4
  a(data-goto="#5") 5
  a(data-goto="#6") 6

main
  p(data-id="1") 1
  p(data-id="2") 2
  p(data-id="3") 3
  p(data-id="4") 4
  p(data-id="5") 5
  p(data-id="6") 6
```

SCSS

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

main {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 500px;
}

nav {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

a {
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  &:hover {
    background: lighten(red, 20%);
  }
}

p {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid 2px green;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

JS

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a'),
    paras = document.querySelectorAll('p'),
    main  = document.querySelector('main');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    var linkID = this.getAttribute('data-goto').slice(1);
    for (var j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
      if(linkID === paras[j].getAttribute('data-id')) {
         window.scrollTo(0, paras[j].offsetTop); 
      }
    }
  })
}
```

PURE JS ONLY PLEASE - NO JQUERY

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use JS rather than just a `href`? (If so, that's fine, I was just wondering)

Comment: @icke it is just the way the backend guy has set things up. href wouldn't work anyway as they're in different containers. And href doesn't smooth scroll

Comment: Different containers, as in, they're loaded in different iframes? Or are they on the same page? I removed all JS from your example, added IDs to the targets and hrefs to the menu items and it scrolled there just fine, though admittedly not smoothly. I feel like I'm missing the point, but I just can't tell...

Comment: @icke as per the codepen, they're in 2 different containers (divs/other elems), not iframes. And the nav links are populated by the backend, which spits out what I have in the codepen with data- values rather than href.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to set the [`scrollTop` property on the `<main>` element](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/svr6qbj5/).

```
var nav = document.querySelector('nav'),
    main  = document.querySelector('main');

  nav.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    var linkID,
      scrollTarget;
    if (event.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "A") {
      linkID = event.target.dataset.goto.slice(1);
      scrollTarget = main.querySelector('[data-id="' + linkID + '"]');
      main.scrollTop = scrollTarget.offsetTop;
    }
  });
```

You'll notice a couple of other things I did different:

- I used [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/) so I only had to attach one event to the `nav` element which will more efficiently handle clicks on any of the links.
- Likewise, instead of looping through all the `p` elements, I selected the one I wanted using an [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors)

This is not only more efficient and scalable, it also produces shorter, easier to maintain code.

This code will just jump to the element, for an animated scroll, you would need to write a function that [incrementally updates `scrollTop` after small delays using `setTimeout`](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/svr6qbj5/1/).

```
var nav = document.querySelector('nav'),
    main  = document.querySelector('main'),
    scrollElementTo = (function () {
      var timerId;
      return function (scrollWithin, scrollTo, pixelsPerSecond) {
        scrollWithin.scrollTop = scrollWithin.scrollTop || 0;
        var pixelsPerTick = pixelsPerSecond / 100,
          destY = scrollTo.offsetTop,
          direction = scrollWithin.scrollTop < destY ? 1 : -1,
          doTick = function () {
            var distLeft = Math.abs(scrollWithin.scrollTop - destY),
              moveBy = Math.min(pixelsPerTick, distLeft);
            scrollWithin.scrollTop += moveBy * direction;
            if (distLeft > 0) {
              timerId = setTimeout(doTick, 10);
            }
          };
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        doTick();
      };
    }());

nav.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var linkID,
    scrollTarget;
  if (event.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "A") {
    linkID = event.target.dataset.goto.slice(1);
    scrollTarget = main.querySelector('[data-id="' + linkID + '"]');
    scrollElementTo(main, scrollTarget, 500);
  }
});
```

Another problem you might have with the event delegation is that if the `a` elements contain child elements and a child element is clicked on, it will be the target of the event instead of the `a` tag itself. You can work around that with something like the [`getParentAnchor` function I wrote here](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/ux7k34se/).

Comment: Thanks so much man! Any recommended tuts/links on making it scroll?

Comment: I've added some code that should do the trick. I would have included it in the original answer but I wrote it around 6am after being at work all night and didn't have the will to do it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand the problem correctly now: You have markup that you can't change (as it's generated by some means you have no control over) and want to use JS to add functionality to the generated menu items.

My suggestion would be to add `id` and `href` attributes to the targets and menu items respectively, like so:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a'),
    paras = document.querySelectorAll('p');

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].href=links[i].getAttribute('data-goto');
}

for (var i = 0; i < paras.length; i++) {
    paras[i].id=paras[i].getAttribute('data-id');
}
```

Comment: Works but it doesn't scroll

Comment: You mean it doesn't scroll smoothly?