# scrollTo not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I have this scrollable list

```
<ol>
    <li>...</li>
    ...
</ol>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jeanluca/5mns79ds/)

Now, I can scroll programatically using

```
document.querySelector('ol').scrollTo(100);
```

But this doesn't work in Safari. Although this seems to be trivial, I cannot find the alternative (without using jQuery)

How to make the list scrollable in Safari?

Comment: Have you tried on other browsers i.e. Google Chrome or Firefox? Is it working there?

Comment: On Google Chrome, it throws error, `Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).scrollTo is not a function`. You can refer my answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scrollTo` is a property of `window` object. And you are trying to apply it on an `element`.

> Use `element.scrollTop`

**Code Snippet**

```
document.querySelector('ol').scrollTop = 100;
```

It will do the trick!

For more information on `scrollTo` & `scrollTop`, refer [Mozilla/Window/scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) & [Mozilla/Element/scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) respectively.

> **NOTE**
>
> `document.querySelector(selectors)` returns the first element within
>   the `document`. If your `document` contains multiple `<ol>` elements,
>   it will always return the first element.
>
> To select specific element, you can assign an `ID` & refer the element
>   by `document.querySelector('#ID')`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is just wrong - `scrollTop` returns a pixel value - `scrollTo` scrolls the window OR an element to a given position - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will help you:
[Scroll to position WITHIN a div (not window) using pure JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381109/scroll-to-position-within-a-div-not-window-using-pure-js)

There is alternative way to get what you wished.